# 0-100mV ADC reading with microcontroller - Suggestions

Tags: stm32, adc, noise

**Why this approach:**
I have to make solution for existing HW components

**HW application description:**
I'm driving matrix of DC motors, with ULN2003. With 2 pairs of ULN2003 I was able to make current sink and current source. Driving motors works well. Every DC motor has microswitch, which in every rotation with microswitch press adds 360Ohm resistor, and pulls line to 0V. Amplitude when motor is driven, is from 80mV to 100mV (~90mV)
[image]
On current sink ULN2003 side, I added this HW layout:
[image]

OUT1 is sensing point for signal shown on oscilloscope picture.

Signal isn't too fast and not too noisy, and shouldn't cause any problem for 12bit ADC from any microcontroller, to read drop to 0V or at least near 0V. Drop as seen on picture is 7ms.

But unfortunately I have problem reading signal with STM32F103.
239clock cycles and 71cycles are good enough to have good sample_time.

[Github link to project](https://github.com/orderbobproject/STM32F103-ADC?fbclid=IwAR2YoACrXS4n77nvZMRiNRWSaGE_iI58ApZKbk8sIxkE33NkSetli_4ChXM).

I'm open to any suggestions, how to make ADC signal reading more accurate, some external LC filter or 10pF capacitor between signal and GND? (oscilloscope probe has it). Some suggestions around clock settings, ADC settings, etc.

ADC settings in CUBEMX:
ADC1 global interrupt enabled
ADC running on 12Mhz, PA1 pin.
[image]

Clock settings:
[image]

Current source with ULN2003:
[image]

Comment: I don't understand your question: *Why? On current sink ULN2003 side, I added this HW layout:* <-- I've shown the full line of text but, the "why" bit doesn't have any context. Additionally, how can a ULN2003 be made into a current source given that they are 7x NPN open-collector transistors in a single package.

Comment: I do not see any question. What do you want to do? (current measuring) Is the noise the problem? (Do you want a more smooth signal?)

Comment: I want ADC to sense this kind of signal. But with current setup I can't, I still didn't identify problem, why. 
Values of ADC reading are not correct and not even close to signal shown on scope picture. They are bouncing and cannot sense ADC signal with correct accuracy.

Comment: Andy aka:
I edited main question with ULN2003 as current source.

Comment: Of topic - them old ULN parts perform very bad in an industrial setting and are prone to easily break. I'd recommend using a "smart high side switch" MOSFET an equivalent, dedicated motor driver IC.

Comment: As for your question, it makes a bit of difference if you measure current or voltage. And also the quality of the ADC supply will matter, which I don't see mentioned in your question. Also make sure to protect the ADC input pins from transients and over-voltages.

Comment: Well, what are your ADC readings? Does the ADC work if you feed it with a clean 100 mV square wave?

Comment: ADC readings are mess, when reading signal which is on first picture. 
When I'm generating square signal with function generator, (50 dutycycle, 90mV amplitude, 10kHz), ADC reads two times 0 and two times 60 (which represents 90mV)